# Delphi SelectClipRGN Hides Drawn Bitmap

Tags: delphi, bitmap, paint, clipping

I am drawing a custom background (derived from TGraphicControl) with a border. After drawing the border in the DrawBorderRect function, I return the "client" area, and want to limit future painting to this new region. Everything works if I do not use a ClipRgn.

Working Code:

```
var
  R : TRect;

begin;
  R := GetClientRect;     //(R -> 0, 0, 300, 200)
  R := DrawBorderRect(R); //(R -> 20, 20, 280, 180)
  Canvas.StretchDraw(R, FBitmap); //FBitmap is a 3 pixel x 3 pixel square
end;
```

Above code gives me this:[image: Output without ClipRGN]

But, I want to use ClipRgn, and I have tried the following. The pattern is not shown this time (But, if I click the mouse button on the area then the pattern shows. So it is working kind of working, but then gets overwritten for some reason ?).

Problematic code:

```
var
  R : TRect;
  ClientRegion: HRGN;

begin;
  R := GetClientRect;     //(R -> 0, 0, 300, 200)
  R := DrawBorderRect(R); //(R -> 20, 20, 280, 180)

  ClientRegion := CreateRectRgn(R.Left, R.top, R.Right, R.Bottom);
  SelectClipRgn(Canvas.Handle, ClientRegion);
  try
    Canvas.StretchDraw(R, FBitmap); //FBitmap is a 3 pixel x 3 pixel square
  finally
    SelectClipRgn(Canvas.Handle, HRGN(nil));
    DeleteObject(ClientRegion);
  end;
end;
```

and I get this (unless I click the left mouse button in which case I see the above)
[image: Output with ClipRGN]

Any insights as to what is going on, and what am I missing?

Comment: Did you see this note in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162955.aspx)? "The SelectClipRgn function assumes that the coordinates for a region are specified in **device units**."  You are specifying the coordinates in pixels instead. Use [`LPtoDP()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145042.aspx) to convert your pixel coordinates into device coordinates.

Comment: BTW, when and where exactly is your clip+drawing code being called from? Your comment about clicking the mouse causing the drawing to appear makes me think you are drawing in the wrong piece of code at the wrong time.

Comment: @RemyLebeau This is all happening in the **form designer**. (This is a design time component that I drop on the form). Clicking the mouse does not show the image when I run the application; it only happens in the designer. Will try the device units in a few minutes.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer about device units. That was the problem. (But I still wonder why it shows the image when the mouse is clicked on the object at design time).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SelectClipRgn` assumes device coordinates.

`TGraphicControl` descendants have a device context retrieved for their parent window. The viewport origin is moved to be able to set the client origin to (0, 0), but they are logical coordinates.

In short, you need to offset your region:

```
...
ClientRegion := CreateRectRgn(R.Left, R.top, R.Right, R.Bottom);
OffsetRgn(ClientRegion, Left, Top);           // <--
SelectClipRgn(Canvas.Handle, ClientRegion);
...
```

Comment: Good catch, I missed the part where the component is a `TGraphicControl` descendant.