# Printing metafile that includes clipping to PDF comes out blank

Tags: delphi, pdf, clipping

I have an application that prepares a drawing to an Enhanced Metafile. To produce output, this metafile is copied to a canvas; either a Paintbox (in custom preview window on screen) or a printer canvas.

All works as expected when displaying in the custom preview or printing to a **physical (!)** printer (any paper format). However, when printing to PDF (I have tried NitroPDF, Adobe Acrobat and Microsoft Print to PDF) whatever was drawn within a clipping region shows up as blank as shown in the screen clips below (left is the expected output, right is the PDF output).

[image]

Note that the clipping is applied **by column** (all headers and columns shown are derived from a TBaseColumn).  The columns header and border are drawn after the clipping region is released:

```
procedure TBaseColumn.Draw(ACanvas: TMetafileCanvas);
var
  P: array [0 .. 1] of TPoint;
  LClipRegion: HRGN;
begin

  // Set temp reference to MetafileCanvas
  FCanvas := ACanvas;

  // Set clipping area
  P[0] := FDrawingRect.TopLeft;
  P[1] := FDrawingRect.BottomRight;
  LPtoDP(FCanvas.Handle, P, 2);
  LClipRegion := CreateRectRgn(P[0].X, P[0].Y, P[1].X, P[1].Y);
  SelectClipRgn(FCanvas.Handle, LClipRegion);
  try
    DrawContent; // Protected method so we can override in derived columns
  finally
    // Reset clipping
    SelectClipRgn(FCanvas.Handle, HRGN(nil));
    DeleteObject(LClipRegion);
  end;
  DrawHeader;
  DrawColumnBorder;
  FCanvas := nil;
end;
```

Note that I have added the LPtoDP conversion based on [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27809840/delphi-selectcliprgn-hides-drawn-bitmap) but unfortunately it seems to make no difference.

There is one other "strange behavior" I have noticed. In the print method of my custom preview, I have several options to draw the metafile to the printer canvas (pmPlayMetaFile is default).

```
procedure TMyPrintPreview.Print(const APrintTitle: string; const APrintMethod: TSD_PrintMethod);
var
  LMetaFileRect: TRect;
  LBmp: Vcl.Graphics.TBitmap;
begin
  if not assigned(FMetaFile) then
    exit;

  if APrintTitle = '' then
    Printer.Title := 'Document_' + FormatDateTime('yymmdd_hhnn', Now)
  else
    Printer.Title := APrintTitle;

  Printer.BeginDoc;
  try
    LMetaFileRect := FPreviewInfo.GetPrinterMetaFileRect(FMetaFileScaling);
    case APrintMethod of
      pmPlayMetaFile:
        begin
          PlayEnhMetaFile(Printer.Canvas.Handle, FMetaFile.Handle, LMetaFileRect);
        end;
      pmDirect:
        begin
          Printer.Canvas.StretchDraw(LMetaFileRect, FMetaFile);
        end;
      pmBitmap:
        begin
          LBmp := Vcl.Graphics.TBitmap.Create;
          try
            LBmp.Width := LMetaFileRect.Width;
            LBmp.Height := LMetaFileRect.Height;
            LBmp.Canvas.StretchDraw(Rect(0, 0, LBmp.Width, LBmp.Height), FMetaFile);
            Printer.Canvas.StretchDraw(LMetaFileRect, LBmp);
          finally
            LBmp.Free;
          end;
        end;
    end;
    Printer.EndDoc;
  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      Printer.Abort;
      raise;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

There is no notable difference using any of these methods. However (and this completely puzzles me), if use a **modal dialog** to allow the user to select the print method (see below) then the output to PDF is as expected.

```
procedure TfrmMain.btnPrintClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  dlgMethod: TdlgPrintMethod;
  LMethod: TSD_PrintMethod;
begin
  if ParamStr(1) = '/p' then
  begin
    // DEBUG PRINTING. Show modal dialog to select "print method"....
    dlgMethod := TdlgPrintMethod.Create(self);
    try
      if dlgMethod.ShowModal = mrOK then
      begin
        LMethod := TSD_PrintMethod(dlgMethod.PrintMethod);
        MyPrintPreview.Print(FFileName, LMethod);
      end;
    finally
      dlgMethod.Free;
    end;
  end
  else
    // NORMAL PRINTING. No dialog, use default method (pmPlayMetaFile)
    MyPrintPreview.Print(FFileName);
end;
```

I am totally puzzled as to why this only happens when printing to PDF and all other output (screen and printer) works just fine.  It must be related to some "setting" but I cannot seem to find it.  I have invested a lot of time in this application and printing to PDF is a must (users must be able to share drawings with user that do not have the application). Rebuilding from scratch (i.e. not using metafile) is there what I am trying to avoid. So any suggestion or direction as to what I may try to fix this is very welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Why putting **one graphic** into a PDFile? Why not simply saving it as a picture file, preferably PNG or some vector format?

Comment: If I remember correctly `Enhanced Metafiles` support having contents in multiple layers. So it is possible that content you draw within clip reign is positioned behind rest of the content and thus being hidden by it. BTW what program are you using for viewing of the created PDF document? In our organization we had problems because when our customers were viewing our documents in MS Edge that they would not be shown correctly. Some elements might be hidden by other elements. OF you would open our DPF in any other viewer it would be shown correctly.

Comment: @AmigoJack That would be a workaround, but I sometimes simply require one of the PDF "printers" (Adobe, Nitro, etc).  I may want to add headers and footers to the page, I may need a PDF to insert into another PDF, etc. So far the practical reasons. Another reason is that I'm trying to understand what's going on and how to fix it (if possible) :-)

Comment: @SilverWarior I am using Adobe Acrobat (Pro & Reader) and NitroPDF.  Not aware of layers in EMF's so will investigate that.  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: https://github.com/synopse/SynPDF does a pretty good job of making PDF's from metafile without having to print them.

Comment: Thanks @PieterB for the suggestion but this is not what I am looking for.  There's no problem printing to a physical printer or producing output (saving, copy & paste) to a certain graphics format. It is strictly about printing to a (virtual) PDF printer that the end user may have installed and then select it to produce output to a PDF file.  As soon as the metafile contains clipping, all clipping regions appear blank (in the PDF, that is).  This was confirmed by temporarily comment out the "clipping code".  Output is then shown (but outside the columns)  :-(

Comment: I stand corrected. The problem occurs with NitroPDF and Adobe Acrobat.  Using the "Microsoft Print to PDF" printer, the problem does NOT occur and the drawing is printed as expected. Question is: what's different in the NitroPDF and Adobe Acrobat printer (canvas)?